# Simple interface for tagging research data?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, tagging

Before I can build a system that automatically classifies text, I need to manually classify a whole bunch of samples as a training/evaluation set. **Is there some existing tool that will let me  manually tag thousands of items without too much pain?** And if not, what's the quickest way to whip something together?

As an example, imagine you have a bunch of Twitter messages. You'd like to put them in particular buckets: happy, sad, funny, angry, and spam. Some things go in multiple buckets. You could just dump everything into a file and insert some tags with vi, but that's error-prone and kinda slow. More importantly, having a nice interface means maybe you can talk your colleagues into doing a bunch of the work. Web, GUI, or console doesn't matter much; just as long as it's quick and easy. Is there anything like that?

I'm hoping yes, although I can't find anything with Google. If I have to build something, is there a good place to start? From rummaging, my first impression is that Rails + jQuery + acts_as_taggable_on + jQuery Tokenizing Autocomplete seems ok, but I'm open to other things.

Comment: Good choice! Rails + jQuery + acts_as_taggable_on + jQuery Tokenizing Autocomplete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, I ended up building something with Ruby's [HighLine](http://highline.rubyforge.org/) module for command-line interfaces. It's not as fancy as a web-based interface, but it was simple to build and, thanks to its single-character mode, very fast to use.

Answer (score 1):

I think Rails + jQuery + acts_as_taggable_on + jQuery Tokenizing Autocomplete, like you mentioned is a good choice!

Answer (score 1):

Amazon Mechanical Turk https://www.mturk.com/mturk/welcome is designed specifically for the use case you describe. It allows you to upload data, create a form, then farm out your classification to people, which then results in a return file.

Comment: Thanks! In this case, we need to do the initial classification internally, so we can discover the correct buckets. MTurk is useful for simple tasks that can be quickly explained to others, but that will come later. Also, MTurk costs money and has major quality control issues, so it's not as easy as one might think: http://behind-the-enemy-lines.blogspot.com/2010/12/mechanical-turk-now-with-4092-spam.html

Answer (score 1):

Why not just go simple and use Excel (or any other spreadsheet program)?

Just have the messages (to be tagged) in the first column, and then create little macro to allow the user (you/colleagues/...) to click the adjacent cell to select one of the buckets. If the message is to be put in multiple buckets, let the user click the next adjacent cell to choose another bucket. (If you want, you can fix the maximum number of chosen buckets by just restricting the number of cells that can be edited).

You will then have all messages tagged in a format that is very easy to upload to a database for further processing.

There is nothing high tech here, which is good for colleagues who may not be computer savvy. Everybody knows how to enter data into a spreadsheet!

Comment: Reasonable notion! In my case, not everybody runs an OS that Microsoft likes, and I don't know a thing about OpenOffice macros. Thanks for suggesting it, though.

Comment: If you like the spreadsheet idea, why not just go with the spreadsheet in Google docs? If your buckets have simple names (single letter/number) and are few in number, a macro isn't necessary either.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go high tech (compared with my earlier low tech Excel answer), you could just use [Weka Tools](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/), which "...contains tools for data pre-processing, classification, regression, clustering, association rules, and visualization. It is also well-suited for developing new machine learning schemes."

Comment: Are you sure this has something for hand classifying the training set? I've used Weka before, and only remember machine-learning tools. I think the "classification" there is the sort of automated classification that I'll be doing later, not the manual classification that's necessary to do first.

Comment: Sorry, you might be right. I haven't used it for a while but remember it had options to group data (files) into sets as part of pre-processing. But just looking now at the recent documentation, perhaps it's not what you need.